# CSS vertical scroll area on mobile over canvas area

Tags: html, css, canvas

Situation: I've got an HTML page with multiple canvas elements on it. The canvas elements stretch the entire page (both vertically and horizontally), and there's no spacing between them.

Now I've got a problem on mobile devices, because if I touch-scroll over these canvas elements, the browser does not recognise this as a regular scroll event, leaving me unable to scroll the viewport at all.

Because the HTML page is taller than my viewport, I still want to be able to scroll to the bottom of the page, which I've now disabled. Any ideas to mitigate this effect are more than welcome.

You can see a demo of what I'm talking about @ http://www.manuals.epaper-system.com/Tutorials/BXSLT4IndV6_220440/BXen/2014/20141115/BXEPen_v6_20141115_V220440.htm

Click on an article, then zoom in (to make the page taller than your viewport), close the article and try to scroll the page on your mobile browser while pinching on the PDF contents.

Comment: Can you give us your code?

Comment: Oh btw, this also happens for the HTML5 <area> and <map> elements.